# hibernate 5 - Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I am able to use sessions if I open a new one, however, I am getting this error if I try to get the current session which I guess doesn't exist.

***persistence-h2.properties***

```
# jdbc.X
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-database
jdbc.eventGeneratedId=sa
jdbc.user=root
jdbc.pass=root_password

# hibernate.X
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate

# hibernate.search.X
hibernate.search.default.directory_provider = filesystem
hibernate.search.default.indexBase = /data/index/default

# envers.X
envers.audit_table_suffix=_audit_log
```

***HibernateConfig.java***

```
package com.buraktas.spring;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-h2.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.buraktas" })
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.buraktas.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        final HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        // Envers properties
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix", env.getProperty("envers.audit_table_suffix"));

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

***PersonDaoImp.java***

```
@Repository
public class PersonDaoImp implements PersonDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Person getPerson(int id) {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return currentSession.get(Person.class, 1);
    }
}
```

Here if I use `sessionFactory.openSession()` instead then I am able to query my database. But I don't want to create a new session and close it every time. I thought I needed to add `current_session_context_class` and `connection.pool_size` properties as well, but that didn't solve the problem. So long story short how I can initialize a connection pool or a session pool?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to open the transaction with `@Transaction`

Comment: @GuillaumeF. thanks I will give it a try

Comment: thanks! Adding @Transactional annotation worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a late response, but as I mentioned in the comments adding @Transactional on class level worked.